# Div within div, and 2 copies of each - jQuery reusable/scalable syntax

Tags: jquery, html, nested

I want to create in Jquery the equivalent of
div "n" within div "a", and 2 of those -- meaning divs a and b, each have 1 child

so I would like something like

1. > $('#box').append(   $('')

> ```
>    .attr("id", "newDiv1")
>    .addClass("newDiv purple bloated")
>    .append("<span/>")
>      .text("hello world")</li>
> ```
>
> where the box would be the main container, and use addClass for adding a single child, then make 2 instances of the boxes.

The purpose of this is to
1) divide the screen into 2 parts (CSS handles the sizing and location, that's done -- and this works fine in Javascript I just want to transfer to jQuery and move the code out into a jQuery file) -- hence the outer divs, 
2) include an arrow in each, hence the inner div, (drawn in CSS, works) which is highlighted when user's mouse is on left/right side of the screen -- hence the inner divs

so all I need is a simple jQuery setup, but done the right way so I can add on to it in the future for other uses. I want an elegant way, and have this be called on page load to create these 4 divs. Detail in the solution would be nice to see.

At this point I only control these divs as follows:

> ```
>           $("#n").toggle();
>           $("#p").toggle();
>           msg="Navigation arrows turned "+($(BLOCK_NEXT).is("visible") ? "On" : "Off");
>           keyUsed=true; break;
> ```

my second question is:
in using $(something), I want that something to be #+VARNAME, but there is no way to do that other than VARNAME contain the # itself, as far as I can tell (I want the pound sign # be added to a variable with only the text name in it)

Comment: This is my starting point, my research doesn't bring answers, it would really help to get an answer -- helping me with the basic understanding of using an object twice, and adding a child to it

Comment: (more detail) I am looking for: 2 main divs, box1 and box2. box1 contains divA and box2 contains divB. Then I want to modify the content of onClick and make it same for box1 and the divA within in, and a different one which is same for box2 and divB. What I want is a generic way of setting up a jQuery object which is a Div and has 1 Div child, then instantiate 2 boxes and have 1 div within each one.

Comment: I have the following which doesn't have right syntax
` $('#out1').addClass("block_left")
           .append( $("")
              .attr("id", "in1");
              .addClass("arrow_left")
           )
`